# How could i show arabic numbers in java tableview int column and make integer sort over it?

Tags: java, sorting, numbers, tableview, arabic

I want to make tableview integer column shown in arabic numbers not in english.
my problem when i convert it using

```
arabicLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguageTag("ar-SA-u-nu-arab")
            .build();
numberFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance(arabicLocale);
numberFormat.format(123);
```

the default sorting make it sorted as String not integer.

Comment: .format parses it to a string, you should in the case of when converted display the string for output.